# - (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact called with NULL nodes

Tags: sprite-kit

Can anyone shed any light on why the method is getting called with `contact.bodyA.node = NULL and contact.bodyB.node = NULL`?

Is this normal behaviour or is it something I am doing that is resulting in this?

If it is normal then is the correct action to check for `NULL` nodes and to then simply ignore the calls?

Comment: Did you mean `contact.bodyA.node == nil && contact.bodyB.node == nil`?

Comment: Yes probably, sorry there is a mix of Swift and Obj-C code...